# How to select subcategories from selected category using a nested function in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data

First of all, I posted another question about this, but didn't get answer so I needed to post a new one.

I have a function which is listing categories hierarchically, I created another function (on same function) with `foreach` loop in, and using it into dropdowns too, so don't need to create another query, using my existing function multiple times.

**I want to use same query to list subcategories under a selected category.**

Example: if `category.php?id=100` clicked, then I want to list subcategories under catgeory 100 hierarchicaly in landing page.

Here is my function :

```
$allCategories = array();
$categoryMulti = array(
    'categories' => array(),
    'parent_cats' => array()
);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
//I created another array to get subcats didnt work
//$categories['categories'][1]
    $categoryMulti['categories'][$row['cat_id']] = $row;
    $categoryMulti['parent_cats'][$row['parent_id']][] = $row['cat_id'];
    $allCategories[] = $row;
}
function listCategoryTree($parent, $category)
{
    $html = "";
    if (isset($category['parent_cats'][$parent])) {
        $html .= "<ul>\n";
        foreach

 ($category['parent_cats'][$parent] as $cat_id) {
                if (!isset($category['parent_cats'][$cat_id])) {
                    $html .= "<li>" . $category['categories'][$cat_id]['cat_name'] . "</li>";
                } else {
                    $html .= "<li>" . $category['categories'][$cat_id]['cat_name'];
                    $html .= listCategoryTree($cat_id, $category);
                    $html .= "</li>";
                }
            }
            $html .= "</ul> \n";
        }
        return $html;
    }
```

Usage : `echo listCategoryTree(0, $categoryMulti);`

And here is how I use in dropdown showing just for an example it works fine:

```
function selectCategories($categories)
{
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo '<option value="' . $category['cat_id'] . '">' . $category['cat_name'] . '</option>';
    }
}
selectCategories($allCategories);
```

And this is one of the examples that i tried to make it work with the selected category method, but unfortunately, it didn't worked.

I created a new array in my function:

```
$subCategories = array();
$subCategories[] = $row;
```

And call it as a function like following but didn't work.

```
function cats($categories)
{
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>' . $category['cat_name'] . '</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}

echo cats(100, $subCategories);
```

Comment: Your code looks OK. What error or warning are you getting?

Comment: Code is ok and working fine in two functions, listing all categories hyerarchicaly and all categories in select box. I need another function on same arrays with where clause, For example: When user click on a category and gone to category landing page, They should see subcategories under that category, I do it with a second query right now, but I wanted it in a function and on same arrays, instead of creating a new query. so I can cal as a function like `echo cats($cat_id, $subCategories);`

Comment: I’m sorry but I’m not sure I understand what you mean by _another function on same arrays with where clause_. Do you want to do it using two separate functions or one SQL query? Can you clarify?

Comment: @N'Bayramberdiyev sorry for my bad english, I want 1 sql query and two functions, Function 1. List all categories hyerarchicaly. Function 2.list sub_categories under specified category. Example  list sub categories under category economy in second function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions. First of all, I'll use the following data (`categories` table) as an example.

```
+----+--------------------------+-----------+
| id | name                     | parent_id |
+----+--------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Electronics              |      NULL |
|  2 | Apparel & Clothing       |      NULL |
|  3 | Phones & Accessories     |         1 |
|  4 | Computer & Office        |         1 |
|  5 | Men's Clothing           |         2 |
|  6 | Women's Clothing         |         2 |
|  7 | Cell Phones              |         3 |
|  8 | Cell Phone Accessories   |         3 |
|  9 | Phone Parts              |         3 |
| 10 | Computers & Accessories  |         4 |
| 11 | Tablets & Accessories    |         4 |
| 12 | Computer Peripherals     |         4 |
| 13 | Computer Components      |         4 |
| 14 | Office Electronics       |         4 |
+----+--------------------------+-----------+
```

[image]

### Solution 1 ([Adjacency List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)):

You can easily fetch either all categories or subcategories of a category in a single query using [WITH (Common Table Expressions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) clause (requires MySQL 8.0):

```
// Database connection

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
];

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<DATABASE_NAME>', '<USERNAME>', '<PASSWORD>', $options);
```

```
function getCategories(PDO $db, $parentId = null)
{
    $sql = $parentId ? 'WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, name, parent_id) AS (SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM categories WHERE parent_id = ? UNION ALL SELECT c.id, c.name, c.parent_id FROM categories c INNER JOIN cte ON c.parent_id = cte.id) SELECT * FROM cte' : 'SELECT * FROM categories';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($parentId ? [$parentId] : null);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

If you're using MySQL 5.7, change that function like so:

```
function getCategories(PDO $db, $parentId = null)
{
    $sql = $parentId ? 'SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM (SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY parent_id, id) c, (select @pv := ?) initialisation WHERE find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) AND LENGTH(@pv := concat(@pv, ",", id))' : 'SELECT * FROM categories';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($parentId ? [$parentId] : null);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

To get all categories in your database:

```
$allCategories = getCategories($pdo);
```

Output:

```
+----+--------------------------+-----------+
| id | name                     | parent_id |
+----+--------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Electronics              |      NULL |
|  2 | Apparel & Clothing       |      NULL |
|  3 | Phones & Accessories     |         1 |
|  4 | Computer & Office        |         1 |
|  5 | Men's Clothing           |         2 |
|  6 | Women's Clothing         |         2 |
|  7 | Cell Phones              |         3 |
|  8 | Cell Phone Accessories   |         3 |
|  9 | Phone Parts              |         3 |
| 10 | Computers & Accessories  |         4 |
| 11 | Tablets & Accessories    |         4 |
| 12 | Computer Peripherals     |         4 |
| 13 | Computer Components      |         4 |
| 14 | Office Electronics       |         4 |
+----+--------------------------+-----------+
```

To get subcategories of a category:

```
$subCategories = getCategories($pdo, 1); // 1 is parent_id
```

Output:

```
+----+--------------------------+-----------+
| id | name                     | parent_id |
+----+--------------------------+-----------+
|  3 | Phones & Accessories     |         1 |
|  4 | Computer & Office        |         1 |
|  7 | Cell Phones              |         3 |
|  8 | Cell Phone Accessories   |         3 |
|  9 | Phone Parts              |         3 |
| 10 | Computers & Accessories  |         4 |
| 11 | Tablets & Accessories    |         4 |
| 12 | Computer Peripherals     |         4 |
| 13 | Computer Components      |         4 |
| 14 | Office Electronics       |         4 |
+----+--------------------------+-----------+
```

If you want an HTML output, you can loop through `$allCategories` / `$subCategories` (based on your example):

```
function prepareCategories(array $categories)
{
    $result = [
        'all_categories' => [],
        'parent_categories' => []
    ];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $result['all_categories'][$category['id']] = $category;
        $result['parent_categories'][$category['parent_id']][] = $category['id'];
    }
    return $result;
}

function buildCategories($categories, $parentId = null)
{
    if (!isset($categories['parent_categories'][$parentId])) {
        return '';
    }

    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach ($categories['parent_categories'][$parentId] as $cat_id) {
        if (isset($categories['parent_categories'][$cat_id])) {
            $html .= "<li><a href='#'>{$categories['all_categories'][$cat_id]['name']}</a>";
            $html .= buildCategories($categories, $cat_id);
            $html .= '</li>';
        } else {
            $html .= "<li><a href='#'>{$categories['all_categories'][$cat_id]['name']}</a></li>";
        }
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

```
echo buildCategories(prepareCategories($allCategories));
```

Output:

[image]

```
echo buildCategories(prepareCategories($subCategories), 1);
```

Output:

[image]

### Solution 2 ([Nested Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)):

We'll add additional columns `left` and `right` to our table and put numbers in it which will identify the groups belonging to the parent. (Note that we won't be using `parent_id` column.)

```
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| id | name                     | parent_id | left | right |
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|  1 | Electronics              |      NULL |    1 |    22 |
|  2 | Apparel & Clothing       |      NULL |   23 |    28 |
|  3 | Phones & Accessories     |         1 |    2 |     9 |
|  4 | Computer & Office        |         1 |   10 |    21 |
|  5 | Men's Clothing           |         2 |   24 |    25 |
|  6 | Women's Clothing         |         2 |   26 |    27 |
|  7 | Cell Phones              |         3 |    3 |     4 |
|  8 | Cell Phone Accessories   |         3 |    5 |     6 |
|  9 | Phone Parts              |         3 |    7 |     8 |
| 10 | Computers & Accessories  |         4 |   11 |    12 |
| 11 | Tablets & Accessories    |         4 |   13 |    14 |
| 12 | Computer Peripherals     |         4 |   15 |    16 |
| 13 | Computer Components      |         4 |   17 |    18 |
| 14 | Office Electronics       |         4 |   19 |    20 |
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

[image]

Now, we need to change our function:

```
function getCategories(PDO $db, $parentId = null)
{
    $sql = $parentId ? 'SELECT children.* FROM categories parent INNER JOIN categories children ON parent.left < children.left AND parent.right > children.left WHERE parent.id = ?' : 'SELECT * FROM categories';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($parentId ? [$parentId] : null);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

To get all categories in your database:

```
$allCategories = getCategories($pdo);
```

Output:

```
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| id | name                     | parent_id | left | right |
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|  1 | Electronics              |      NULL |    1 |    22 |
|  2 | Apparel & Clothing       |      NULL |   23 |    28 |
|  3 | Phones & Accessories     |         1 |    2 |     9 |
|  4 | Computer & Office        |         1 |   10 |    21 |
|  5 | Men's Clothing           |         2 |   24 |    25 |
|  6 | Women's Clothing         |         2 |   26 |    27 |
|  7 | Cell Phones              |         3 |    3 |     4 |
|  8 | Cell Phone Accessories   |         3 |    5 |     6 |
|  9 | Phone Parts              |         3 |    7 |     8 |
| 10 | Computers & Accessories  |         4 |   11 |    12 |
| 11 | Tablets & Accessories    |         4 |   13 |    14 |
| 12 | Computer Peripherals     |         4 |   15 |    16 |
| 13 | Computer Components      |         4 |   17 |    18 |
| 14 | Office Electronics       |         4 |   19 |    20 |
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

To get subcategories of a category:

```
$subCategories = getCategories($pdo, 1); // 1 is parent_id
```

Output:

```
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| id | name                     | parent_id | left | right |
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|  3 | Phones & Accessories     |         1 |    2 |     9 |
|  4 | Computer & Office        |         1 |   10 |    21 |
|  7 | Cell Phones              |         3 |    3 |     4 |
|  8 | Cell Phone Accessories   |         3 |    5 |     6 |
|  9 | Phone Parts              |         3 |    7 |     8 |
| 10 | Computers & Accessories  |         4 |   11 |    12 |
| 11 | Tablets & Accessories    |         4 |   13 |    14 |
| 12 | Computer Peripherals     |         4 |   15 |    16 |
| 13 | Computer Components      |         4 |   17 |    18 |
| 14 | Office Electronics       |         4 |   19 |    20 |
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

You can render HTML as shown in **Solution 1**. [Read more](https://www.waitingforcode.com/mysql/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-nested-set/read) about updating and inserting new data in nested set model.

---

Sources & Reads:

- [Managing hierarchical data in MySQL - nested set](https://www.waitingforcode.com/mysql/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-nested-set/read)
- [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)
- [Models for hierarchical data](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)
- [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL Using the Adjacency List Model](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-adjacency-list-tree/)
- [Adjacency list vs. nested sets: MySQL](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/29/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-mysql/)
- [One more Nested Intervals vs. Adjacency List comparison](https://vadimtropashko.wordpress.com/2008/08/09/one-more-nested-intervals-vs-adjacency-list-comparison/)

Comment: More than perfect, Thank you so much.

Comment: Solution one is  what I wanted `$subCategories = getCategories($pdo, 1); // 1 is parent_id`.  there no way to thanks enought for your effort.

Comment: Managing hierarchical data may be a bit tricky. I once have dealt with it. And I highly recommend to use OOP for better organizing your data.

Comment: Just a question is null equal to 0 ? in my table value is 0, both functions works fine, just for an idea.

Comment: They're both falsy. But their types are not equal. null is a `NULL` and 0 is an `integer`.