# PHP function not showing data from dropdown menu

Tags: php

Currently creating 2 dropdown menus, one for category and one for subcategory. My current function shows all data on the page only for subcategories but not for categories. Why is this happening?

***Current Functionality:*** User selects a category, page refreshes and is blank. Once user selects SUBcategory it shows all products in that subcategory.

***Desired Functionality:*** User selects a category, page refreshes and shows all products in that category. Once user selects subcategory it shows all products in that subcategory.

```
function populate_search_catsub()
{
    global $link;
    $subcatt = "";
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM item';
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $catt = $_GET['catt'];
    if (isset($_GET['subcatt'])) {
        $subcatt=$_GET['subcatt'];
    }
    $nbprod = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE cat='$catt' AND field='$subcatt'");

    if (!isset($_GET['catt']) || $_GET['catt'] == '') {
        unset($_GET['catt'], $_GET['submitsearchsub']);
        populate_main();
    } else {

        if (isset($_GET['subcatt'])) {
            echo '<span>Search results for Category="'.$catt.' And Sub Category='.$subcatt.'"</span><hr>';
        }

        $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE cat='$catt' AND field='$subcatt'");

        if ($cat = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            echo '
                <div class="itemlist">
                    <span><h3>'.$cat[1].'</h3><h6><a href="#"><u>View</u></a></h6></span>
                    <div class="col-lg-12" style="background-color: white;"><br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-right: 2%;">
                                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x210"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
            ';
            while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                echo '
                    <div class="itemlist">
                        <span><h3 style="display:inline;">'.$cat[1].'</h3><h6 style="display:inline; margin-left: 1%;"><a href="#"><u>View</u></a></h6></span>
                        <div class="col-lg-12" style="background-color: white;"><br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-right: 2%;">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x210"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                ';
        } else {
            if (isset($_GET['subcatt'])) {
                echo "<h2 >No results found</h2>";
            }
            unset($_GET['catt'], $_GET['submitsearchsub']);
            populate_main();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334057/how-to-select-subcategories-from-selected-category-using-a-nested-function-in-ph/59598800#59598800). Let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: `!isset($_GET['catt']) || $_GET['catt'] == ''` is the same as `empty($_GET['catt'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, grab `$_GET['catt']` and `$_GET['subcatt']`. Then, you can build a query based on these parameters. And please, use [`mysqli_num_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to check if there are more than zero rows returned.

```
function populate_search_catsub()
{
    global $link;

    $catt = $_GET['catt'] ?? ''; // Requires PHP 7.0 or upper.
    $subcatt = $_GET['subcatt'] ?? '';  // Requires PHP 7.0 or upper.

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `item`'; // Initial query

    if (!$catt) {
        unset($_GET['submitsearchsub']);
        populate_main();
    }  else {
        $query .= " WHERE `cat` = '{$catt}'";

        if ($subcatt) {
            echo '<span>Search results for Category="' . $catt . ' And Sub Category=' . $subcatt . '"</span><hr>';
            $query .= " AND `field` = '{$subcatt}'";
        }

        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { // Check if result set is not empty.
            while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                echo '
                    <div class="itemlist">
                        <span><h3 style="display:inline;">'.$cat[1].'</h3><h6 style="display:inline; margin-left: 1%;"><a href="#"><u>View</u></a></h6></span>
                        <div class="col-lg-12" style="background-color: white;"><br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-right: 2%;">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x210"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                ';
        } else {
            if ($subcatt) {
                echo '<h2 >No results found</h2>';
            }

            unset($_GET['catt'], $_GET['submitsearchsub']);
            populate_main();
        }
    }
}
```